# Dart await keyword

Tags: dart-async, dart-io, dart, dart-rpc

I want to try the rpc package of Dart using the io sample (https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc)

I'm on the 64 bits version of Dart editor with the 1.9.1 sdk (cannot update more thans stable version)

This is my pubspec.yaml :

```yml
name: myDartRestServer
version: 0.0.1
description: A minimal command-line application.
#author: <your name> <email@example.com>
#homepage: https://www.example.com
environment:
  sdk: '1.9.1'
dependencies: 
  rpc: any
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: any
```

But when I try to copy the sample for launch my server :

```dart
final ApiServer _apiServer = new ApiServer('/api/', prettyPrint: true);

void start() {
    _apiServer.addApi(new Synchro());
    HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 9090);
    server.listen(_apiServer.httpRequestHandler);
    _apiServer.enableDiscoveryApi("http://localhost:9090");
}
```

My EDI(SDK) don't know the await keyword. (I import the dart:io dart:async and rpc package in my library file)

I've missed something? Thanks by advance for your responses. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mark the function as `async` in order to be able to use `await`

```dart
void start() async {
  ....
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a5170ff293b861b3db6b)

Without `async` `await` is a valid identifier.

Comment: I missed that, sorry! Thank you very much for your help.